# How to create a Powershell scipt to automatically connect to o365 and run as a schedlued task

Tags: powershell, calendar, automation, scheduled-tasks, office365

I would like A PowerShell script to automatically connect to office 365 and to run as a scheduled task twice a day, THEN assign Reviewer permissions to new users if not possible then reviewer for all users. the reason being is because when a new user is created in outlook 365 their calendar permissions are set to free/busy.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you take a look at: [OfficeDev/PnP - TimerJob](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.SimpleTimerJob)

> Shows how to create "remote timer job", which could be installed to be running as a WebJob to Windows Azure or scheduled to windows scheduler for on-premises deployment.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible, with the obvious downside that you'll need to store credentials for an account with permissions to edit all user calendars by default to run the script with.

There are two parts to the script that you'll require:

#### Connecting to Exchange Online

As [shown here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984289%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), connecting to Exchange Online is a very simple process.

Leaving the question of how to store credentials in a secure method out of scope of this question, this will result in a PowerShell session to the Exchange servers:

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
```

#### Selecting New Users

You'll then need to either select the new users (by passing them to this script, or scanning AD - this will depend on how you're creating your users - synced from AD or just created in-cloud), and apply the permission change to them. However...

#### Changing Default Permissions on Calendars

In this case, as I don't know how you're creating the new users, or how best to test that, I'm simply applying it to everyone. This will take far longer in a large environment, and is just a pretty bad idea.

```
Get-Mailbox -Filter {RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox' -and IsShared -eq $false}| %{ 
    Set-MailboxFolderPermissions -Identity "$($_.Alias):\Calendar" -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer 
}
```

Finally, according to the original article, you should close the remote session.

```
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

#### Scheduled Tasks

After fixing the issue with credentials, you'll then want to save the script (ensuring that it complies with the Execution Policy on the system you'll be running it on), and create a new scheduled task to run it.

Configure a Scheduled Task as appropriate (in terms of triggers and conditions), and set the Action as `Start a program`, with that program being `powershell.exe`. Arguments should include `-File C:\Path\to\Saved\Script.ps1` and any arguments (such as a file of new users).

---

Having said all of that, what you should actually do is [change the sharing policy in 365](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj916673%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which will allow you to set the default permission for calendars.